# How can I make RestSharp use BSON?

Tags: serialization, json.net, restsharp, bson

I'm using RestSharp, and using Json.NET for serialization (see [here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/86b31f9adf049d7fb821de8279154f41a17b36f7/RestSharp/Serializers/JsonSerializer.cs)).

Json.NET supports BSON, and since some of my requests have huge blocks of binary data, I think this would speed up my application dramatically. However, as far as I can tell, RestSharp does not seem to have any in-built support for BSON.

The use of Json.NET is implemented as a custom serializer for RestSharp, and so at first glance it looks like it would be possible to modify that custom serializer to use BSON. But, the `Serialize` method of the `RestSharp.Serializers.ISerializer` interface returns a `string` - which is (I assume) unsuitable for BSON. So, I assume that it would take some more significant changes to RestSharp to implement this change.

Has anyone figured out a way to do this?

---

Update: I looked at the RestSharp source, and discovered that the `RestRequest.AddBody` method that takes my object and serializes it into the request body eventually calls `Request.AddParameter` (with the serialized object data, and the parameter type `RequestBody`).

I figured that I might be able to serialize my object to BSON and then call `Request.AddParameter` directly - and indeed I can. However, when RestSharp then executes the `RestRequest`, it fails to put the binary content into the request, because there are other embedded assumptions about the request content being UTF-8 encoded.

Thus it looks like this hack would not work - there would need to be some changes made to RestSharp itself, and I'm not the man for the job...

---

Update 2: I decided to have a go at using the debugger to figure out how much of RestSharp I'd have to change to overcome the body-encoding issue, so I swapped out my NuGet version of RestSharp and included the RestSharp project in my solution. And... it **worked**.

It turns out that there has been a change to RestSharp in the last few months that isn't yet in the NuGet version.

So, you *can* now use `AddParameter` and pass in an already-BSON-encoded object, and RestSharp will send it off to the server without complaint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the updates in my question, it turns out that if you have the latest RestSharp source, then instead of this:

```
        request.AddBody(myObject);
```

... you can do this instead whenever you have a payload that would benefit from using BSON:

```
        using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var bsonWriter = new Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.BsonWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                var serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();

                serializer.Serialize(bsonWriter, myObject);

                var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

                request.AddParameter("application/bson", bytes, RestSharp.ParameterType.RequestBody);
            }
        }
```

Note that the first parameter to `AddParameter` is supposedly the parameter name, but in the case of `ParameterType.RequestBody` it's actually used as the content type. (Yuk).

Note that this relies on a [change](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/commit/f808f09c086d8e50de8dfd71e653b199877bb63b) made to RestSharp on April 11 2013 by ewanmellor/ayoung, and this change is *not* in the current version on NuGet (104.1). Hence this will only work if you include the current RestSharp source in your project.

Answer (score 3):

Gary's answer to his own question was incredibly useful for serializing restful calls. I wanted to answer how to deserialize restful calls using [JSON.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). I am using RestSharp version 104.4 for Silverlight. My server is using Web API 2.1 [with BSON support turned on](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/bson-support-in-web-api-21).

To accept a BSON response, create a BSON Deserializer for RestSharp like so

```
public class BsonDeserializer : IDeserializer
{
    public string RootElement { get; set; }
    public string Namespace { get; set; }
    public string DateFormat { get; set; }

    public T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(response.RawBytes))
        {
            using (var bsonReader = new BsonReader(memoryStream))
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                return serializer.Deserialize<T>(bsonReader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, ensure your request accepts "application/bson"

```
var request = new RestRequest(apiUrl, verb);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/bson");
```

And add a handler for that media type

```
var client = new RestClient(url);
client.AddHandler("application/bson", new BsonDeserializer());
```

Comment: This answer helped me a lot, in case anyone is getting an exception "Sequence contains more than one element" when adding the handler, I fixed it by adding Handlers before adding Default Headers to the RestClient instance